# PayPal IPN for echeck

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Does paypal sends an IPN notifications to your callback url on clearance of an **echeck transaction** ?

I was testing an echeck transaction in PayPal Sandbox. The app received echeck transaction notification with **payment_status** as "**Pending**". After manually clearing the transaction from PayPal account, the app didn't received any kind of notification.

I was expecting a second IPN notification with same txn_id and payment_status as "Completed" or "Cleared". Is it not so ?

Answer (score 3):

I am getting notifications when echecks clear, at least in production (not sure about sandbox).

Source: my Website Payments Standard (with enhanced recurring payments) Paypal IPN recent transaction history and my application's log.

Here are a few fields from the original IPN notification and the cleared one, which in this case came about 5 days later.  They both have the same transaction ID.

original, pending:

```
txn_type=subscr_payment
payment_date=[initial date]
pending_reason=echeck
payment_type=echeck
payment_status=Pending
```

cleared, completed:

```
txn_type=subscr_payment
payment_date=[initial date]
payment_type=echeck
echeck_time_processed=[process date]
payment_status=Completed
```